# Rewrite custom post type URL in search

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website in which I have a custom post type (guest authors from [CoAuthors Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/)). With [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extended-search/) I managed to make post of custom type "guest author" searchable by WordPress legacy search.

Now, the authors are correctly shown in search results. Although, they are linked to a wrong page, `/?post_type=guest-author&p=2148`, which brings to a 404.

I'd like to be able to get the URL, interprete it, and redirect to the correct page (which is in the form of `/archives/author/name-surname/`.

I'm trying to get it working with a rewrite URL, but I'm not able to catch the data and formulate the rewrite.

Comment: Seems like a permalink settings problem. One thing you could try is going to Settings->Permalinks. There simply click « Save ». Did the trick for me at some points. If not, check the permalink settings for mistakes. You might want to check what these permalink settings are all about. https://wordpress.com/support/permalinks-and-slugs/

Comment: I do not think is a permalink question, more an indexing error of search extender. I am looking for a code solution that allows me to manually correct the link.

Comment: So, you did try and save the permalink settings?

Comment: Yes I did, nothing new...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code changes the permalinks for `guest-authors`. It uses the methods from the CoAuthor plugin that output the guest authors link.

At least now you have the correct links according to the plugin's intentions.

They will be in the form:

```
{site_url}/author/{author_slug}
```

Here is the code to include in functions.php:

```
function adjust_permalink($permalink, $post){
    $post_type = get_post_type($post);
    if($post_type === 'guest-author'){
        global $coauthors_plus;
        $author = $coauthors_plus->get_coauthor_by('ID', $post->ID);
        $permalink = get_author_posts_url( $author->ID, $author->user_nicename );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link','adjust_permalink',10,2);
```

Now, you should be able to create your template php file for author in your theme: `author.php`

Comment: I can't find the words to say how thankful I am: you definitely saved my night (and, probably, my weekend)!